# Odd behavior in logger Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I was trying to add some logging statements in my rails 4 application and ran into this odd behavior.

I defined an instance variable called blah as

```
@blah = 'test'
```

Now if I do this

```
logger.debug 'this string is #{@blah}'
```

the output is

```
I, [2014-01-27T13:36:06.047288 #8864]  INFO -- : this string is #{@blah}
```

But If I do this

```
 logger.info "this string is #{@blah}" #note the double quotes
```

the output is

```
I, [2014-01-27T13:36:00.236707 #8864]  INFO -- : this string is test
```

Seems like string interpolation within logger works only if the string is enclosed with double quotes and not single quotes. Is this normal? If so, anyone knows why?

Comment: String interpolation does not work with single quotes.  It only works with double quotes.

Comment: @MaheshGuruswamy By design.

Comment: @MaheshGuruswamy Because that's how it works.

Comment: @MaheshGuruswamy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation#Ruby

Comment: I suggest reading a basic Ruby tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
> rp@foo:~$ irb
> 2.1.0 :001 > @foo = 'bar'  => "bar" 
> 2.1.0 :002 > '#{@foo}'  => "\#{@foo}" 
> 2.1.0 :003 >
> 2.1.0 :003 > "#{@foo}"
> => "bar"
```

this is how its supposed to be.